# Java - calculating the area between 2 polynomials

Tags: java, math

I know there are ways to estimate the area between 2 curves (e.g. Rectangle rule, trapezoid rule, Simpson's rule, etc.), but if I have polynomials

e.g.

```
f1(x) = a1x^3 + b1x^2 + c1x + d1
f2(x) = a2x^3 + b2x^2 + c2x + d2
```

Is there a library/function that can calculate the exact area between 2 polynomial curves?  Perhaps by finding the integral of f1(x)-f2(x)?

Comment: If you have polynomials, calculating the integral should be a fairly simple exercise, you don't need to estimate.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: This seems more like a math problem than java problem.

Comment: @Codebender It's not even much of a maths problem, the integral of `a*x^n` is simply `a / (n+1) * x^(n+1)+C`. Though that would give you a "signed" area, which may not be what OP is after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to find difference polynomial `G(x) = f1(x)-f2(x)` and calculate absolute values of definite integrals on intervals between its zeros (or specific border points).

Comment: Pardon me for wondering, but how does this answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the area under a curve using the Apache Commons Math library. Their [numerical analysis](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/analysis.html) section has the functions needed to compute integrals.

If you have two polynomial functions `f` and `g`, all you need is to compute the integral of `f - g` (as you already mentioned).

In particular, look at the classes [SimpsonIntegrator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/analysis/integration/SimpsonIntegrator.html) and [TrapezoidIntegrator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/analysis/integration/TrapezoidIntegrator.html) for the two approaches you mention in your question.

Comment: There is no need to use approximation methods because simple exact solution exists for polynomials